# Nested partial views or multiple partial views best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, partial-views

I am looking for advice and thoughts on an ASP.NET MVC application I am working on.
This application contains reviews on various services and reviews with star rating appear on different pages for different products, users or customers.
Is it a good practice to create a different partial view for star rating and comment etc and insert as partial views inside views where they are meant to be used.
Or I should create individual views with these components repeated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is no silver bullet advice for that question, besides there are not only partial views approach to separate your logic, additionaly you can render the whole controller action inside view (kinda child action) or use html helper. It is your job actualy to find the best way because you know the context :)

But if we are talking only about star rating component i would consider using custom html helper for that